# how to continuously deploy with long running jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, background-process, sidekiq, delayed-job

We currently use delayed_job and rails to manage some long running jobs in our system. Some of these jobs take potentially hours to run, but we also like to deploy rather frequently, often many times a day. The problem with this setup is that we have to restart delayed_job during deployment to pick up code changes, so that any new jobs are processed with the latest code.

The solution we've arrived at is that for any job that needs to run for more than some small amount of time, we fork the delayed job so that it returns immediately, and the forked process handles the work. This way a deploy can restart all the delayed job processes, while the long-running 'job' keeps going until it's finished as an orphaned process.

We've looked at sidekiq, but it looks like we'd have the same issue there when trying to deploy new code.

Has anyone developed a solution they would recommend for dealing with long-running background processes that span multiple deployments?

Comment: The Sidekiq recipe is to split the work into many smaller jobs and process them in parallel.  If your job takes many hours, perhaps it is better modeled as a long-running rake task that exits when finished and ignores deploys.

Comment: Thanks Mike. One of things I like about delayed job is that it is able to serialize the object to have a method run later on. We've used rails runner to spawn a new process from the command line for long running reports, and rake as well, but that relies on building up a command line string which isn't always practical.

Comment: Sure, but serialized data is also a "cache" that can get out of date, esp if you are retrying the job over many hours or days.  This is why Sidekiq mandates simple data types like DB IDs.